# iphone run app as root

Tags: iphone, gcc, root, jailbreak

I am writing a gui wrapper for gcc for a jailbroken iphone, etc. and it is almost done. However, I get this output when it is run `ld: can't open output file for writing : a.out, errno=1 collect2:ld return 1 exit status`.
I believe this has to do with the privelages the app runs with. I have tried the setuid trick in the cydia developer faq. Can anyone please help?

**EDIT**
this is the wrapper I am currently using:
`#!/usr/bin/bash

dir=$(dirname "$0")

exec "${dir}"/GUI\ GCC_ "$0"`
also I used chmod 4777 and changes the owner:group to root:wheel.
Am i doing everything right?

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit late, but chmod 4777 is refused from the Springboard (your app should crash on launch). You should use 755, owner:grout root:wheel

Answer (score 2):

It worked when I did it like this:

setuid(0);
system("Do root stuff");

// To check who you are
system("whoami");

You can install the Package for "ps -U root" to see if you are root, or

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your have your setuid binary hidden behind a wrapper that is not setuid. See Cydia or iFile for an example of how it's done.